# Flag never handled

Tags: support, moderator-tools, flags

[A question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/10661/869) was flagged, and subsequently closed before anyone handled the flag. It doesn't show up in the flag queue, or on the post when viewing it (other than the "1 flag" floating box). However, it doesn't seem to have ever been deleted, or have a result.

[image]

Shouldn't "Community ♦" show up in the "Deletion User" column, and "Helpful" in "Result"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a fun edge case.

1. It was a custom flag that *I believe* would not have gotten dismissed regardless, though I'm a little hazy on that.
2. The flag was raised by a user who had too many declined flags and their flag weight (which still exists behind the scenes) has dropped to zero. This basically means that their flags are never shown to moderators at this point and just about everything in our systems ignores them.

There currently isn't a way that I know of for someone to recover from this flag hellban, though that's balanced out by it being fairly difficult to hit. I'm hoping we can put something in place to make it even harder by warning folks when they've had a string of declined flags. That's a ways out, though, pending some dev work around flag handling.

Comment: "I'm hoping we can put something in place to make it even harder by warning folks when they've had a string of declined flags." Is there an open question on this?

Comment: @Sam Not that I know of, but maybe. I plan on making one to solicit some ideas when we're closer to being able to make it happen.

Comment: I like the idea, for what it's worth I suggest: When a rapidly descending user clicks "flag" they should be shown a window that succinctly explains that they should / need to read about flag's appropriate uses (with links to detailed information and their history) instead of the real flagging window. Basically try to teach them the moment they are about to make the mistake.

Comment: @Sam That's exactly the direction I'm thinking of going.

Comment: *There currently isn't a way that I know of for someone to recover from this flag hellban* - could we get some reliable confirmation regarding whether or not this is possible?

Comment: @Jim I've asked around before and it doesn't look like recovery is possible. To recover, you'd need to gain flag weight, and to gain flag weight you need someone to handle your flags. Since your flags now go into the void, you can't get any of them marked helpful via any means.