# Allow recovery from flag hellban

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-ban, hellban

Currently, users can get stuck in a permanent flag hellban from which there is no recovery.

> I've asked around before and it doesn't look like recovery is possible. To recover, you'd need to gain flag weight, and to gain flag weight you need someone to handle your flags. Since your flags now go into the void, you can't get any of them marked helpful via any means. – Adam Lear♦ [Mar 27 '13](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173864/flag-never-handled/173867#comment518517_173867)

Users can enter this hellban even if they have many more helpful flags than declined flags. Subsequently, their future flags are never reviewed, despite the likelihood of being helpful.

I suggest allowing users to recover from this ban in the following way:

- User must have more helpful flags than declined flags (perhaps somewhere in the 1.5:1 to 3:1 range?)
- Hellban flags are tracked silently. If another user flags the same post (and that flag is marked helpful), or if the post is deleted, the flag counts as "helpful" (not actually marked helpful until the user is unbanned).
- Once the user reaches a certain threshold (perhaps related to measurments that trip the hellban) of "helpful" flags, and at least 2/3 of their hellbanned flags are "helpful", the ban ends.

This allows good users who get hellbanned because of a bad streak to come back from it.

Comment: I'd assumed we would see them if they ended up being part of a larger group of flags.

Comment: I thought the same as @Flexo, which would mean that there _is_ a way for someone to escape flag hellban. If that's not the case, let's just reset flag weight (for flag banned users) after <arbitrary amount of time>, why complicate things?

Comment: Interesting...I thought I had read somewhere that Stack Overflow didn't actually implement the hellban. Under what circumstances do hellbans occur?

Comment: @Yannis That's a pretty good idea. A lot simpler, too. Only downside is anyone who consistently raises bad flags will start popping up in the flag queue with junk again every once in a while. It'd be nice if we could only allow good users to escape.

Comment: @JackManey Anna Lear spelled it out [pretty clearly here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173867/148672)

Comment: @Jack This is only a *flag* hellban, which means the user's flags are ignored. Stack Exchange does not implement a *full* hellban, which is when a user thinks they can participate normally, but no one sees there posts so they never get a reply.

Comment: From what I remember, helpful and unhelpful flags both affect flag weight by 10, except when your flag weight is over 500, and flags are ignored when your flag weight hits 0. Therefore, the only way to have more helpful flags than unhelpful flags and still have your flags ignored is to have previously had a flag weight above 500, which means you had a streak of 50+ unhelpful flags more than helpful. I don't think there is enough chance of it happening to worry about it, and if a user has a bad streak that long, do we really want to let them recover?

Comment: Could we see some data about how many users are actually affected by this? I'm guessing a very small number and an even smaller one with previous good flagging history

Comment: @ughoavgfhw It doesn't take a streak that long. This question was prompted because I discovered a hellbanned user who didn't have terribly many declined flags, and had approx 3x helpful.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw We can certainly do better at warning folks that they're on a bad path. I'm okay with providing a path to recovery as well, since unlike other contributions that have multiple ways to get feedback (like posting low-quality questions and getting downvotes, for example), flags are very much a "fire and forget" kind of thing and people generally do flag with good intentions, even if they are ultimately wrong. Intentional flag abuse (as in, trying to spam the flag queue with bogus flags) is rare to nonexistent.

Comment: @AdamLear not entirely non-existent. We've had some users who knowingly and intentionally abused the flag system (one of them "didn't like close votes", despite having 10k). The flag hellban is quite nice in those situations.

Comment: @nhinkle Fair point. There are other ways to handle that (such as suspensions), so I'm not too worried about it. Or we could potentially implement a system similar to review bans.

Comment: @AdamLear I think a full-on suspension for a user who's otherwise fine but has serious flag quality issues is overkill, but if there were a manual ban (like with review bans) that would certainly cover these cases.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

#### Update: Kevin Montrose makes it happen

The **hell-ban** is no more! Long live the verbose, obnoxiously evident ban!

Kevin has implemented (more or less) the system described below. Flaggers with a recent (past 7 days) flagging history consisting of at least 10 handled flags where >= 10% of flags were declined will see the following when they flag:

[image: Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!]

Those who've had 25% or more of their flags declined will see:

[image: Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!]

...and will be unable to flag any further posts for any reason.

Folks who've flagged fewer than 10 posts in the past week whose most recently-processed flag was declined will see:

[image: Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!]

Flags considered for the purpose of these warnings / bans are currently limited to *post flags* which often require explicit moderator intervention: Other, Spam, Offensive, Very Low Quality, Invalid Flag, Close and Not an Answer. I'm not 100% on the value of including close flags in this: we spot-tested these criteria with and without them at various times, and the downside to including them is that they can end up making some folks' flagging histories look better than they appear to the moderators. However, these *are* listed on the flag summary page that's linked to from the warnings, so for now we'll include them and see how it plays out in practice.

Hopefully, this will help less prolific flaggers learn to use the system correctly without repeatedly wasting their time and that of the site moderators.

We'll be keeping an eye on this and adjusting these thresholds as-needed. Please report any problems you encounter here on meta, using the tag [declined-flags](/questions/tagged/declined-flags).

---

We're in the middle of a *major* re-write of the entire flagging system. As part of this, we're re-thinking how flag weight (and thus "hell bans") work. Adam & I have been discussing this for a while - here's what we're looking at doing *instead:*

- **Only look at folks who cast at least 10 flags a week.** There isn't much point in doing much to knock the priority of flags from people who rarely flag anything.
- **If at least 10% of your flags from the past 7 days were declined**, you'll get a little warning next time you go to flag something... Along with a link to your flag history so you can see *exactly* where the problems arose.

  [image: flag warning]
- **If at least 25% of your flags from the past 7 days were declined**, you're blocked from flagging anything. Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week.

  [image: flag block]
- **For users with less than 10 flags in the past week,** look only at the status of the last flag - if it was declined, then warn as above (but with the message "Your last flag was declined..."). This handles the case where new users are confused as to what "flag" is supposed to be used for.

Over time, the flag system has evolved from a rather opaque "I saw a problem, please do something" system into [a way for everyone to work hand-in-hand with the elected moderators](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/). For this to be effective, it must include *feedback* on how well you're flagging - closing that feedback loop should help our more prolific flaggers to become better at flagging, and reduce noise for the moderator teams.

Comment: "This must necessarily include feedback on how you're - " I think you accidentally a word. Also, is the "10 flags a week" a rolling average, cumulative average, per-week number..?

Comment: Thanks @Hydronium - and yes, it'd be a sliding window.

Comment: This all is great, but please, for the love of the flying spaghetti monster, give us a way to [dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities). 25% of your flags from the past 7 days seems like it could be affected by bulk approvals / rejections and may lead to unjustified bans.

Comment: One other important aspect of this would be to enable mods to selectively act on specific flags on a post. If the flag feedback gets more prominent, the cases where users receive the flag feedback meant for another user will get more noticeable and more confusing.

Comment: FWIW: there's only 1 person on Stack Overflow who meets the "ban" criteria right now, and 19 who would be warned (more would've been banned a few days ago though). There are 13 people with 0 flag weight... None with over 100 flags total, all of who took months or even years to hit the flag-ban.

Comment: @Yannis That should be addressed by the rewrite as well, last I heard.

Comment: my understanding is, the planned changes keep the [guidance on marking helpful / declined in September 2011 Moderator Newsletter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160331/165773 "part quoted here") intact, is that correct?

Comment: That guidance is fine up to the point where folks are prolific and extremely wrong (flagging wrong answers instead of down-voting, using spam flags for off-topic questions, etc) - we don't want to be too harsh, but teaching folks bad habits isn't good either, @gnat. On Stack Overflow and a few other large sites, there are additional concerns since flags feed into review. We'll probably update that guidance eventually - we're moving further and further away from the "max out your flag weight!" system that made declined flags so painful.

Comment: I see, "prolific and extremely wrong". This seems to be covered by guidance as well, doesn't it? I mean, right before all this nice talk about _trying to err blah blah_, article clearly instructs decline to "deter serial abusers of the flagging system"

Comment: @gnat: keep in mind, moderators don't necessarily have this information in front of them. It's pretty easy to see when someone flags 30 short answers with "should be comment" back-to-back, but a bit harder when they're trickling in at a constant rate. Right now, the latter is actually more likely to get folks flag-banned if mods are being too generous with "decline" - this would change that.

Comment: I see, that's an interesting nuance, I didn't think of it before

Comment: @Shog9 is this 6-8 weeks away, or is there a more concrete target date?

Comment: Since there's a rewrite going on anyway, could [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/allow-moderators-to-reply-to-a-flag) be implemented? While the "too many of your flags have been declined" message does help fix some of the problems listed there, it won't work for the cases when a good flagger has the occasional declined flag that I want to teach him about, and when a flagger has a helpful flag that I want to give him more info about.

Comment: Er, unless there's some major "you done goofed" feedback involved, it seems like this system would mean that A) we can constantly be pestered by crap flags 9 (but not 10) times a week with no reprisal B) even the most blatant, deliberate flag abusers can pester us every other week at least 10 times. Is there any protection here from people that aren't spamming *dozens* of crap flags all at the same time? Because that's totally not how crap flags have worked in my experience.

Comment: @BenBrocka "even the most blatant, deliberate flag abusers can pester us every other week at least 10 times" No they can't, we have a suspend button for that. And yes, I realize that suspending someone for incorrect flags sounds harsh, but so does "blatant, deliberate flag abusers". If they are, suspend and forget.

Comment: @Yannis: Not to mention *we already do that here* :)

Comment: @Yannis that makes sense...maybe provide some way of knowing which users have recently/repeatedly been flag-banned then? If we have to manually suspend offenders it would be nice to know who they are (without having to have manually dismissed billions of their flags)

Comment: @Ben: the scenarios you're describing (consistent but very low-volume bad flags) are very unusual... And not particularly disruptive. Yes, it allows for a theoretical worst-case scenario involving very short, high-volume bursts of bad-faith flagging... But as Bolt notes, those occurrences are already trivial to detect and deal with. (FWIW: most declined flags by a single person for all time on SO: 292 out of 477; on UX: 15 out of 104)

Comment: @Shog9 - little advice. If you go for absolute numbers in your formulas (-> the "10 flags/week" in the first example) try to scale them to the specific site traffic. 10 flags may seem nothing on a site but may be too much for others.

Comment: As for *"Only look at folks who cast at least 10 flags a week"*, it seems that such was not implemented? My (rare) flags still do get handled. If I'd know they would be ignored, then I'd not flag at all anymore. (It takes me a bit of time to put all details in the very limited allowed character count of "other" flags! Silently ignoring would kind of offend me, to be honest.)

Comment: @Arjan: perhaps I need to reword that. The intent is to not bother trying to flag-ban (or rate-limit) people who are already flagging so infrequently that it doesn't matter - the old system was notorious for banning folks who flagged a few times a year.

Comment: So someone throws ten flags, of which one is declined (and nine are deemed correct or not yet handled). When he throws his eleventh, he's told "many of your recent flags have been declined". That's an odd message to get under the circumstances.

Comment: There's an even odder edge-case possible for 3 declined flags followed by 7 good ones, @msh210. Our observations so far indicate that these would be fairly rare though.

Comment: Since your last comment, have you seen more users with at least 3 declined flags in a row? I see a lot of them. I don't want to have to look at the *same person* knowing they are going to flag "urgent plz help", up to 10 times, before they get banned. I might as well suspend their account entirely at 3 declined flags since they probably won't really learn how to use the site.

Comment: @Shog9 how does this work with active flags?  Does this only county handled flags in the last 7 days, or all flags?  And if it counts all flags, how do the active flags factor into the formula?

Comment: My last comment was specific to the scenario where someone screws up three times out of 10 with only 10 flags in a given week, @Bolt. Not 3 flags, all failed, in a given week or any other combination of mostly-failure but less than 10 total in a given week (which are much more common). Before we crank the screws on this, it's worth letting it run a while to see how many folks actually pay attention now that we give them a heads-up that there's *something to pay attention to*.

Comment: It counts handled flags, @psubsee2003. If you drop 30 flags in the queue before any of them are handled, you're not going to see anything. Note that the normal rate-limits still apply though: new users only get 10 flags a day: if you use them all and they're all declined, you're banned for the rest of the week.

Comment: OK, I reread your answer - so it looks like the new system will account for those scenarios by first warning the user. And you'll (well, we will too) monitor this and see how users respond to the warnings.

Comment: Correct, @BoltClock'saUnicorn

Comment: @Shog9 : With this type of system, is it possible to be banned from flagging because *(and immediately after)* of getting an helpful flag?

Comment: Yes, it is @user2284570. Well, strictly-speaking you could be banned immediately after the 10th flag of yours is *processed* (in a 7-day window).

Comment: @Shog9 : Even when [processed as helpful and it is the fourth flag *(before the 10th)*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253496/2284570 "Flag banned after getting a helpful flag") in the past 7 days? I also mean : is it possible to be banned with less than 10 handled flag in the past week?

Comment: No. But there's also no way for you to tell (at this point) how many flags have been handled in the past week. @user2284570

Comment: @KevinMontrose : Well, as I said I can put the ~10 screenshot of my olds post, since there is the date of the handling. I just need to find a suitable area; times; and someone to review them *(I did it for me)*.

Comment: The first page of my flagging history spans 3 months and holds roughly 50 flags (if I counted correctly). Two were disputed, my third-most-recent flag was rejected and the rest was helpful. Considering this flagging history, seeing a warning message doesn't feel all that great to be honest.

Comment: @KevinMontrose 1. Both 'Review before flagging' or 'review instead of flagging' are used, which seems merely inconsistent, and the former implies that you can review and then flag, when in fact you have to wait out the ban. 2. 'Your most recent flag' isn't correct. It is the most recently processed flag. Not the same thing, and [misleading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284246/207421). I have no better wording to suggest, but it needs improving. It also needs reviewing whether implementing it as most-recently-processed is really fair to the user, or really accomplishes the objective.

Comment: How do *disputed* flags factor into this? Since you only talk about percentage *declined*, does disputed count the same as helpful for the purposes of flag bans/warnings?

Comment: Disputed flags get no special treatment, @Randal'Thor. They aren't helpful and they aren't declined; for the purpose of this particular set of tests, they're no different than flags that are still pending or have aged away or been otherwise invalidated.

Comment: These images are quite outdated. For the benefit of new users what about including the new flag images. Of course the images don't take away the point of the article so it is fine if they are left

Comment: @Shog9 So for clarification this appears to be 'if X% of your flags are *declined* in the last 7 days'? I don't flag posts a ton, but when I do it can take a while for them to get handled... 3 of mine just got rejected and none of them were cast by me within the last 7 days (but it still got me post-flag-banned)

Comment: Correct, @TylerH. Also it's a rolling 7 days, so a bunch of flags marked helpful on Monday followed by a bunch of flags declined on Tuesday can still result in a ban *next* Tuesday.

Answer (score 27):

An alternate method of recovery:

I've notice that these flags appear in the queue if other users have flagged the same post. However, marking these flags as helpful doesn't increase the user's helpful flag count, and shows no change to the flag in their flagging history.

**If any other (non-hell-banned) user flags the same post, the hell-banned flag should come out of the void and act as a normal flag.** Once the user no longer meets the criteria for the ban, it is lifted.

Answer (score 9):

Although I would prefer a more systematic, automated approach, it is worth noting that it is technically possible to raise hellban by manually "resetting" user flagging history.

One case when it has been done at Super User is described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109912/165773). In brief, there was sort of a strong community consensus that particular series of flag declines deserves an exceptional treatment. Following this consensus, user contacted SE team and developers removed some of their flags from database.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JQ86.jpg]

Comment: Probably worth emphasizing that this was appropriate *because* the flags were seen as reasonable and not deserving of being declined. Clearing a user's flag history after they've raised a bunch of bad/abusive flags and then later repented is considerably less likely.

Comment: @Shog9 agree, screen shot shows in particular that decision has been made upon quite a thorough meta discussion - I think this is as far from anything _automated_ as it gets