# Do declined comment flags contribute to becoming hell banned?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, comment-flags, hellban

As per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175395#175395) - it seems dismissed flags on answers/questions eventually can allow your flags to not be seen.

I had asked about how frequently we should [flag comments](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/how-aggressively-should-we-flag-comments) on a beta site.

[This answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1794/2322) discusses how flagging comments/comment trains is desirable *even if* the moderators will decline them on their judgement.

But, I don't really want to flag enough comments doing this that I actually become banned from **any** of my flags (comment/answer/question) being recognized.

So:

- Do declined comment flags affect your "flag weight" (which affects the status of becoming hellbanned)?

Comment: Interesting, there was a [reference question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) about flag weight, which may contain the answer to your question, but it has been deleted, so it's 10K-only now.

Comment: It is _extremely hard_ to find yourself flag banned, especially if you have a few helpful flags, so even if comment flags count (they probably don't) you shouldn't really worry about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do declined comment flags count towards the ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337430/do-declined-comment-flags-count-towards-the-ban)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declined comment flags don't reduce your flag weight. We can't see the flag weight anymore, but when we were able to see it they didn't affect it.

And you should not worry about flag weight anyway, SE is currently overhauling the whole flag system, so everything will change anyway and I guess that flag weight will cease to exist in this exact form.

Comment: Any links on the overhauling?

Comment: @Seth http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/151385

Comment: I guess I am assuming this is the correct answer to this question... :-)