# Do declined comment flags count towards the ban?

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags, flag-ban

It seems like only **post** flags' declination counts towards the ban.  Do declined **comment** flags also count towards the ban?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, declined comment flags do not count toward flag bans.

As per the [post announcing the current flag ban system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/377214):

> Flags considered for the purpose of these warnings / bans are currently limited to *post flags*

Also, see [this chat message from an employee (Shog9)](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7158012#7158012):

> [You] don't get banned for comment flags

These are both confirmed by personal testing.

Note, however, that declined comment flags *are* considered when calculating your net helpful flag count to see how many flags you can cast daily, and will negatively impact it.

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

The flag ban requires that 10% of your handled *post flags* in a week be declined. Comment flags marked either helpful or declined have no bearing on the ban.

This is from personal experience - I've been in situations where if comment flags counted towards the ban I would have gotten flag-banned, and the other way around - if the helpful ones counted for *not* being banned I could have avoided a flag ban.

So comment flags aren't counted for the ban, but they are counted for both the Deputy / Marshal badges and the increased flag allowance per day the more helpful flags you've raised.