# Flagging content on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, flags

What happens when a user flags content (question or answer or a comment) on Stack Overflow?  Is the flagged content sent to moderators?  How does Stack Overflow make sure that flagged content is, in fact, really inappropriate content, and not a malicious flagging good/relevant content?

Comment: Certain close flags go to 3k+ users

Comment: Depends on the nature of the flag. Some flags go to 3k users, some to 10k and some only to diamonds.

Answer (score 11):

- Spam and offensive flags go to moderators (and six of them will automatically delete the post)
- Vote to close flags (duplicate and "should be closed for another reason") go to the close vote queue (which is available to 3k+ users)
- Very Low Quality and Not An Answer go to both the mod queue and 10k queue
- "Other" flags go to moderators only

Comment: I look at the lqp queue a lot, but do not understand how a given article actually arrives in that queue in the first instance.  How is that queue populated?

Comment: @GarryVass You mean the "low quality posts" review queue on the review page, or the very low quality posts in the 10k queue?

Comment: the ones I see as a 3k guy.  I look at them all the time and frequently suggest to the op that he pull up his socks.  But how on earth did it get noticed in the first instance?  Is it an auto algorithm?

Comment: @Garry Yes, the ones in the review queue are automatically selected because of length and content.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Stack Overflow make sure that flagged content is, in fact, really inappropriate content, and not a malicious flagging good/relevant content?

Excessive bad flagging i.e. big number of rejected flags will lead to revoking the ability to flag. Once upon a time there was something called *flag weight* that was affected by every single flag and determined how many flags you had and what's your priority in the queue. However that was [replaced not long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/152859).

In short, in the new system if one cast at least 10 flags in a week and 25% of them are declined, he's being blocked from flagging (after getting a warning) for one to seven days.

Comment: How do moderators review this content. Do they have a special website, or a page on this site to look at all the items in queue, and mark them as "Yes it is spam", "No I don't think it is spam"

Comment: @user462455 they have a page on the site, I assume similar to the review queues we have.