# What's exactly the mechanism for showing "Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined"

Tags: bug, flags, declined-flags

<s>Yes, yes, yes, I have seen [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223444), but it doesn't seem to be the case for me.</s> marking it as dupe because @Animuson [clarified thigz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/223444/revisions).

I am getting this message when I click flag on Stack Overflow:

> [image]

However, my last declined flag is from feb 28 - a month has passed already. Since that moment I had 32 helpful flags, 5 aged away, and 3 pending - and no declined.

What's the reason behind this notice being shown for me?

Comment: That flag from Feb 28 was just declined 4 hours ago, though.

Comment: @Ani quoting from the linked answer: "...you've raised *in the past 7 days*... "

Comment: Your previous comment was correct, it only ever looks at the process date. The date the flag was actually created is not relevant at all.

Comment: @ani wait, that answer is incorrect then?

Comment: Not so much incorrect as missing a word.

Comment: @Ani ...drastically changing the meaning though :)