# Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I just got this warning when trying to flag a post:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please
>   [review](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2459641) them before flagging this post!

but I dont get this. When I click on the link, I see all my **recent flags** as helpful or pending. Also in total I have 5 declined flags of 252 total flags. 
I've read this question before of course:

[Why am I seeing the message "Some of your recent flags have been decline" when flagging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223382/why-am-i-seeing-the-message-some-of-your-recent-flags-have-been-decline-when-f)

and the answer is:

> The warning is triggered when at least 10% of the flags you've raised,
>   processed in the past 7 days, have been declined.

Al though I have no declined flags in the past 7 days.

My last declined flag was on March 23rd. That's longer than 7 days ago and it's also not 10% of my flags.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ***"processed in the past 7 days"***. You could have your *older* flag *processed* (or *reviewed*, if you like this wording more) recently.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the statement is probably more correct when reworded:

> The warning is triggered when a recent flag has been declined and at least 10% of the flags you've raised have been declined.

So if your flagging history is worse than 90% accepted, but your recent flags have been good, then you won't get a warning box.  However if your flagging history is worse than 90% accepted and one or more of your most recent flags have been declined, then you'll start getting warnings.  Further, if you haven't flagged recently, or you flag very infrequently, you will never see the warning no matter how bad your flagging history is.

Comment: Still the **AND** part doesn't apply for me according to my math(and I am asian so dont doubt my mathematical skills). If it is indeed **recent** instead of 7 days, I have 1 declined flag out of 20. Which is 5%. If Nicael is right, and it's about **processed in the pas 7 days**, I had 10 helpful flags in the last 7 days (so this means they are processed in the last 7 days as well). I got 1 declined somewhat 9 days ago, which we'll assume is processed this week. So that will be 1 declined out of 11 this week. Which is 9%(9.090909090 etc...) So they round it up to 10% maybe?

Comment: My comment also assumes that just the declined post is processed this week and none of my older helpful flags has been processed this week. Very unlikely but possible

Comment: @Loko Perhaps one or more of your "recent" accepted flags fell more than 7 days ago.  Keep in mind that your time zone and the stack exchange network time zone is different.  A day starts at 0:00UTC for Stack Exchange. However, my post is one possible reason - I don't have access to the code and have no real insight.  It might not be correct.  How about you just flag more judiciously for the next day or two and see what happens, test the system out and report back.

Comment: The thing is. The 11 flags I am talking about are definitly processed in the last 7 days since the flags are 6/7 days old. The timezone thing might be it. I'll try some stuff out though.