# Space between the "Your recent flag was declined" warning banner and the "Flag question" button is too cramped

Tags: bug, design, declined-flags, flag-dialog

[When too many of one's recent flags have declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223444/313042), one receives a warning banner when opening the flag dialog box:

> Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

This banner fills all the space right up to the "Flag question" button, just touching it:

> [image: Flag warning dialog box]

This might be a bit pedantic, but this spacing looks really cramped: can the Flag Warning banner be thinner, or can the spacing between the banner and the "Flag question / Cancel" buttons be increased?