# Burning down the close queue has blocked me from flagging

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I was recently greeted with the message on Stack Overflow:

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

So I go and do that and find that I only have one declined flag in the last month. And by that I mean of all of the flags I've raised in the last month, only one was declined.

However, I'm guessing that because we had a [bit of a BBQ this last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) that my long list of active flags are only now getting reviewed. Even though that is the case, I only have a total 14 declined flags ever. I don't remember how many I had before, but I remember it being very low, like 3–4. I have 320 helpful flags and another 101 waiting review.

Should I really have been flag banned? Also [this answer on flag banning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/219005) doesn't say how long I have to wait.

Comment: I knew I must have missed a post somewhere. Thanks @Servy.