# My flagging privilege on SO was revoked, then I got it back, made a "helpful" flagging, then revoked again

Tags: support, privileges, declined-flags, flag-ban

My flagging privilege was probably removed with the following error message:

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

Although my flagging stats were the following:

```
182 moderator attention flags
45  waiting for review
109 deemed helpful
5   declined
23  disputed
```

I initiated a dispute, partially about the revoking of my privilege, and about another questions as well. You can see that in my history here on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/244746/peter-horvath?tab=questions

After that I got my flagging ability back, without any explanation.

It enabled me to flag the following post as "very low quality": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013623/how-can-i-add-my-site-to-java

This flag has got a "helpful" decision from the moderators.

But currently I can't flag again.

What is going on?

P.s. Please don't try to redirect me to my flag summary, I copy-pasted my flagging statistics from there.

Comment: Perhaps *another, different flag* was declined?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that you had a few flags marked as helpful which lifted the ban and then declined which placed the ban again.

Comment: @PeterHorvath The ban is automatic, we don't control flagging bans.

Comment: Servy has explained the general situation here, but in your specific case, since you got your flagging ability back you have one helpful post flag, one declined post flag, one helpful comment flag, and one declined comment flag. Because the ban threshold is 25% declined flags, if you were right below that threshold, getting 50% of your new flags declined knocked you back above it.

Answer (score 21):

Whether or not you are banned is based on the percentage of declined flags that you have over the past 7 days.  Every single instant in time that passes can potentially change that value.  Not only do new flags coming in matter, but the flags that are no longer within that time period matter.  When a rejected flag becomes old enough to be outside of that time period, it improves your rejection rate.  When helpful flags move out of that time period it harms your rejection rate.

Your ban was removed because one or more of your rejected flags moved outside of that window.  You were banned again due to helpful flags passing through that window.

Also keep in mind that this is all based on when a flag is actually decided on, not when its flagged.  If a flag was declined that you had cast two weeks ago, that could result in you being re-banned, if you were right on the border.

Comment: Per [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/135615): "If at least 25% of your flags from the past 7 days were declined, you're blocked from flagging anything. Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week." So enough flags were declined to kick above 25% for the last 7 days.

Comment: +1 for knowing the flag ban system better than I do.

Comment: The contribution he has on meta, I think Servy is an **undercover StackExchange employee**

Answer (score 3):

> 45  waiting for review

Most likely, one or more of your old flags was declined, pushing you back over the flag-ban threshold.

Comment: Possibly, but not necessarily, as is described in my answer.