# Review message in flag interface doesn't go away after review

Tags: support, flags

I am usually pretty accurate with my flags, but this time I got tricked.

There was a question with one line of text and a link to an image that boasted about subscription totals and signing up. I flagged it as spam, but it was actually about the background of the subscription image.

It has since been deleted. Here is the url: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27291476/1026459 (10k only)

Screen of question:

[image]

Okay, so you got me. I accidentally miss-flagged. :)

However, now *every* time I click flag on a post, I see this:

[image]

The message to review the flag wont go away. I have reviewed it from every angle, but it won't go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't go away until you have another flag that gets processed. [From the Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405):

> Folks who've flagged fewer than 10 posts in the past week whose most recently-processed flag was declined will see:
>
> [image: Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!]

Comment: Ah, I see. That means this is by design then.