# "Declined in the last 7 days" confusingly appears to list only flags cast in the last seven days

Tags: bug, status-completed, declined-flags, flag-history, flag-ban

The [flag ban system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253497/603977) does its calculations using the dates that flags are *handled*, not when they are *cast*. When at least 10 flags have been handled in the last 7 days, if more than 25% of those flags are declined, you're not able to cast any flags.

This causes a dire-looking banner to appear above one's flag summary linking to flags "declined in the last 7 days", i.e., those that have caused the ban. Which looked like this in my case, on the 24th of March:

[image]

Only one flag listed there, which shouldn't be enough to trigger a ban. This was extremely confusing, and led me to wonder if there was a manual ban that had been applied to me. I can't find any mention of such a feature, though.

There are tooltips on the "results" field of handled flags, showing the resolution date, so I tried counting manually and eventually found that indeed I had 2 other declined flags in the previous 7-day span:

[image]
[image]

I didn't know until looking into this even further that I [*can* see handled flags by category, ordered by handling date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268372/159251). So I can easily find these two flags, but **N.B.** that the spam **flag that triggered** the ban **is not listed** with them, which are categorized separately under "post flags". There's no filter view that shows me these three together.

This is confusing and frustrating,<sup>*</sup> but easily fixable. The link that tells me it's showing me flags **"declined in the last 7 days"**, which is **what I need to know**, should just **show exactly what it says**.

Right now it appears to display flags *cast* in the last 7 days, that were declined. Not the same thing, much less useful, and importantly, not its apparent intention (thus I've tagged this as a "bug").

---

<sup>*</sup>With [54 flags declined of 2,708 cast, I tend to think of myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276077/tweak-the-math-for-the-new-flag-ban-system-a-little) as generally being useful when flagging, and I couldn't really understand why my flags were suddenly deemed not so.

Comment: As an editorial aside, getting flag banned because of the **coincidence** of **only three** flags cast **over the course of a month** being declined within a week of each other is, to put it mildly, _discouraging_. I would strongly urge consideration of [the MSE question I linked about tweaking the calculation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276077/159251), or something like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, the query for declined flags contributing to a flag ban was using the flag creation date instead of the flag decline date.

I've updated that query to use the correct date - this will be with you in the next build (meta rev 2016.3.31.4335, other sites: rev 2016.3.31.3411).

Comment: Well, I hope I never have to see it again, but thanks for fixing it!