# Your last flag was declined - no it wasn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, declined-flags

I went to flag something, and in the flag dialog I got the message

"Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!"

[image: last flag was declined]

That's all well and good, but when I went to review my flags, the statement is not accurate.  My last 5 flags were all marked 'helpful'.  The 6th down the list is marked 'declined', but that wasn't my last flag.

The message should probably be modified to correspond to the actual condition that triggers it.  Perhaps it should say

> One of your flags was recently declined - please review it before flagging this post!

I'm going to guess that this message is triggered if, of all the flags of mine that have been handled by a moderator, the one that was most recently handled was declined. This isn't necessarily the last flag that I raised (the one I raised most recently), as moderators might handle them in a different order than I raised them, and it's not necessarily the flag at the top of the list.  Thus, calling it my "last" flag seems like it could cause confusion.

Yes, I realize this is extremely minor.

Comment: It definitely could be worded better, as what it means is "Your last _processed_ flag was declined" rather than "Your last _raised_ flag was declined", the latter being what a lot of users interpret it as. A wording along those lines would certainly help.

Comment: This isn't minor at all, because [the out-of-order calculation leads to brain-dead flag bans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277475/declined-in-the-last-7-days-confusingly-appears-to-list-only-flags-cast-in-the#comment898967_277475) for otherwise good flaggers (yes, I'm talking about myself). Making it hard to figure out what's going on only makes that worse.

Comment: Actually IMO that banner should also go away once you clicked on the link to check which flag got declined. However, it keeps nagging me now for a week because of that old two declined flags, even after having cast over ten helpful flags afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting today, this message now reads:

> Your recent flag was declined - please [review](/users/current?showDeclined=true) it before flagging this post!

...and links directly to the list of your recently-declined flags.