# Wording of declined flag can be confusing

Tags: bug, flags, declined-flags, wording, warning

> [image: "Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!" message shown near the "Flag question" button]

"Your recent flag was declined" can be confusing. Which recent flag? My recent one was helpful (really), which is why I bring this up, because I thought I had *another* recent one declined.

**Compare:** Your recent comment was confusing. (When you've left more than one comment.)

"A recent flag you raised was declined" could solve the problem, but may be harder for pluralization because of the "A", so as a suggestion for the whole line:

> Please [review] your recently declined flag(s) before flagging this post!

---

Note: pressing on "review" does not dismiss the warning – [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), I don't know, but this was mentioned in a comment, so I asked a tie-in: [Is the 'recently declined flag' warning supposed to get dismissed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377202/392799)

Comment: _Does_ it mean the most recent one rather than a recent one? Is that not [a link to a recent flag of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323063/253246)?

Comment: @francescalus: The current wording "means the most recent one, but that's not always the case, which is why I bring this up (my recent flag was helpful)." Unless I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: I agree that the language is a bit clunky. It doesn't necessarily refer specifically to your most recent flag, but it's still kinda ambiguous and weirdly phrased. Maybe make it "You _recently had a flag_ declined - please [review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377200/wording-of-declined-flag-is-not-accurate/#) it before flagging this post"?

Comment: I agree it's not the best way of writing what is meant, but it doesn't say "most recent" and from context with the link it also doesn't intend to say "most recent". You can address my first comment here as "your recent comment" and I won't assume you mean this one.

Comment: @francescalus: "Your recent flag [singular]" grammatically *does* imply the most recent, e.g. *How was **your recent trip** to downtown?*

Comment: Not to me, it doesn't. Bit I also wouldn't say "to downtown" so I guess we have different linguistic heritage. If you do interpret "your recent" the same as "your most recent" then you have satisfactorily addressed my comment.

Comment: @francescalus: Maybe that was not the best example: by "to" I meant to refer to the trip itself, say a bus ride or the traffic *to* downtown, not say the traffic downtown itself.

Comment: @francescalus: I just saw the comment edit you made re "recent comment", and now I'm having second thoughts.

Comment: You meant to say the _recent_ comment edit :).

Comment: @francescalus: Maybe I meant to say: *I just saw **your recent comment** edit [you have three], and now I'm having second thoughts.* Very vague of me... :P Not having those second thoughts now, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @francescalus: please see the post update and let me know if I got my point across any clearer :)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the message means that you must [click on the word review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2JVL.png) to dismiss that notification permanently, if you have flags pending and those too are declined you'll get a new message, until it is dismissed the reminder will be displayed for each new flag. --- Because I don't have proof this isn't an answer; not something I want to test.

Comment: @Rob: I clicked on review and it wasn't dismissed. And I just double checked.

Comment: @zcoop98: If (I don't know) they account for pluralization, "a flag" is still an issue, I think.

Comment: [That](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377200/wording-of-declined-flag-can-be-confusing#comment1257558_377200) was working a few weeks ago, of course I only had one declined, but if it's broken I believe you; and voted accordingly.

Comment: Add this URL (after fixup) to the site's name to show all declined flags, then you can check out the newest one: /users/flag-summary/UserNumber?status=3

Comment: @Rob: thanks Rob; I asked [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377202/392799).