# Is the 'recently declined flag' warning supposed to get dismissed?

Tags: support, bug, flags, declined-flags, warning

> [image: flagging popup]

I was [recently told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377200/wording-of-declined-flag-can-be-confusing#comment1257561_377200) pressing on "review" *(highlighted above)* should dismiss this warning for the next flag raised, but that is not the case at least as of asking this.

If it's meant to dismiss it, apart from fixing it, may I also recommend dismissing it **when the flags page is visited** after a flag is declined?

If it helps: the declined flag was on a *question,* and as shown above that's a *flag question* popup.

Comment: Do you have more than one recently-declined flags?

Comment: @AdrianMole: no, just the one, on the Aviation site.

Comment: I personally think this comment from the site is a bit insulting. On Ask Ubuntu I just got this, and I have over 1200 helpful flags on that site (with **5** declined flags); I don't need to be told how to properly flag posts. Perhaps the software should take the user's entire track record into account before issuing this comment.