# Serial removal of [flag-weight] tag in progress via suggested edits - should we do anything?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, meta, serial-edits

I see a large number of proposals in the Suggested Edits queue right here on Meta Stack Exchange where the same user is trying to serially edit out (bulk untag?) the [flag-weight](/questions/tagged/flag-weight) tag.

I understand that the concept of Flag Weight is [obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/336163) and that some of these questions are arguably not truly *about* flag weight per se (though, when it existed it was very relevant to a lot of flagging scenarios, as negative flag outcomes pushed that number down), but the number of edits queued up gives me some pause. Should we go ahead and edit the tag out of all but a few old questions that directly relate to what flag weight used to be? If not, should we go ahead and reject all these edits?

Comment: Tag removal should be done by users with full editing privilidges, wether needed or not this is not the appropriate course of action.

Comment: I would have submitted the same edits even if flag weight had still been a thing. As you said, the questions are not truly *about* flag weight per se, which means the tag does not belong on the question.

Comment: Approve or disapprove of each edit you review as you see is correct, too many wrong results in a review ban; much for same as an errant editor may face an edit ban. --- I presume someone is doing some reasonable cleanup, some "Flag Weight" tagged questions are entering the review queue for closing: "OT - The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.". What I've seen thus far seems OK.

Comment: That someone is me.

Comment: Bumping is real on low-traffic sites, like meta sites (but not at all at Stack Overflow main), so self-imposed rate limiting (say, one per day) is imperative.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if `flag-weight` should be *added* to this question . . . ;)

Answer (score 5):

I looked at a few of the questions edited, such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/66532). Removing the [flag-weight](/questions/tagged/flag-weight) tag from the questions seems reasonable - the question isn't about the flag weight system.

In general, the [flag-weight](/questions/tagged/flag-weight) tag should be kept. Even if the system as it existed back then no longer exists, it should be kept for organizing old questions about it, although perhaps with a notice in the tag wiki except that the system has been deprecated.

Side note - flag weight isn't *entirely* obsolete. Your flag history does affect the ordering of flags in the moderator dashboard, so it's possible that the [flag-weight](/questions/tagged/flag-weight) tag could be applicable for questions relating to that. But the tag should definitely not be completely removed.