# Warning stating "some of your recent flags have been declined" is incorrect

Tags: feature-request, flags, wording, flag-history, warning

When [greater than 10% of your flags handled in the last 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405) have been declined you'll get a notice in your flag dialog indicating that some of your recent flags have been declined:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please [review](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current?showDeclined=true) them before flagging this post!

This would suggest that your recent *flags* are where the problem is, however by clicking through the link to review your recent flags the heading makes it clear that it's your recently *declined* flags that matter (as in, the date the flag was *declined* is important, the date the flag was *raised* is not):

> Flags raised by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) which were declined in the past 7 days

For example, I have raised 6 flags in the last 7 days (or 8 depending on where you start counting), all marked helpful, however yesterday a flag I raised on July 10th (18 days ago) was declined, which has resulted in the warning being shown.

Can the text in the notice be updated to correctly indicate what has caused it to be shown (note that *"recent"* has been moved to affect the action of being *"declined"* rather than the *"flags"*):

> Attention: some of your flags have been declined recently - please [review](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current?showDeclined=true) them before flagging this post!

Comment: Is that really a *hyphen* I see in the message? It should be an en-dash.

Comment: This looks like an unfortunate side effect of the flag-handling times being too long. Decreasing those would make the issue irrelevant, correct?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Or an em dash if the site uses US styling.