# What should I do about a flag ban?

Tags: support, declined-flags, ban, flag-ban

I was banned from flagging because "too many of my flags have been declined". What should I do about this? Will it be automatically lifted, or am I banned forever?
My flag history:
[image]

Comment: Looks like it only considers your flags in the past 7 days: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban

Comment: Please read [my advice on flagging](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92764/conversation/advice-on-mod-flagging). As a specific example, you flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65878015), but your request was unclear. It probably sounded like you were wanting a mod to improve the answer. What you probably wanted instead was to have the question's close reason changed from "duplicate" to "typo/not reproducible". If you had requested *that*, there's a much better chance that your flag would have been marked helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're raising custom moderator flags when you should be using more standard flags or possibly not flagging at all.

1. You custom flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878015/why-does-if-not-operation-or-or-or-give-me-a-syntax-error) to say that a closing brace is missing. Well we have a standard flag for typos. Per [the Stack Overflow Help Centre on closure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) i.e.

   > Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error.
2. Similarly with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818060/color-and-empty-cell-or-add-text-to-an-empty-cell-via-css) which you also flagged with a custom flag when the community can reopen it without moderator intervention if necessary. If you earned the open/close vote privilege you could have voted to reopen it, but absent that [your options are more limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).
3. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65829438/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-button-tkinter-python/65829892#65829892) is an answer. It may not be a correct answer but it is an answer and you [can't flag incorrect answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) because moderators are not experts in every possible technology so they can't judge technical correctness. If you think the answer is wrong, downvote it.